# MATLAB: Fast calculation of Adamic-Adar Score

Tags: algorithm, performance, matlab, network-programming, vectorization

I have an adjacency matrix of a network, and want to calculate the Adamic-Adar score. It is defined in the following way: For each pair of edges x and y, let z one of their common neighbors, and |z| is the degree of the neighbor.

Now the score is defined as a sum over all common neighbors z:

[image]

See for instance [this paper, page 3](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/link-pred.pdf).

I have written a small algorithm for MATLAB, but it uses two for-loops. I am convinced that it can be made much faster, but I dont know how. Could you please indicate ways how to speed this up?

```
% the entries of nn will always be 0 or 1, and the diagonal will always be 0
nn=[0 0 0 0 1 0; ...
    0 0 0 1 1 0; ...
    0 0 0 0 1 0; ...
    0 1 0 0 0 1; ...
    1 1 1 0 0 0; ...
    0 0 0 1 0 0]; 

deg=sum(nn>0);
AAScore=zeros(size(nn));

for ii=1:length(nn)-1
    for jj=ii+1:length(nn)
        NBs=nn(ii,:).*nn(jj,:);
        B=NBs.*deg;
        C=B(B>1);
        AAScore(ii,jj)=sum(1./log(C));
    end
end
AAScore
```

I would appreciate any suggestion, thank you!

---

**Comparing runtimes**

My nn has ~2% entries, so it can be approximated by:

```
kk=1500;
nn=(rand(kk)>0.98).*(1-eye(kk));
```

- My double-for: 37.404445 seconds.
- Divakar's first solution: 58.455826 seconds.
- Divakar's updated solution: 22.333510 seconds.

Comment: @Divakar, yes, it will always be 0s and 1s only. (i edit the question)

Comment: What's the typical size of `nn`?

Comment: The typical size of nn is between 5000x5000 or 6000x6000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, get the indices in the output array that would be set, i.e. non-zeros. Looking at the code, we could notice that we are basically performing `AND-ing` of each row from input matrix `nn` against every other row. Given the fact that we are dealing with `1s` and `0s`, this basically translates to performing matrix-multiplication. So, the non-zeros in the matrix-multiplication result would indicate the places in the sqaured matrix output array where the computation is needed. This should be efficient as we would be iterating over lesser elements. On top of it, since we are getting a upper triangular matrix output, that should further reduce the computations by using a mask with `triu(...,1)`.

Following those ideas, here's an implementation -

```
[R,C] = find(triu(nn*nn.'>0,1));
vals = sum(1./log(bsxfun(@times,nn(R,:).*nn(C,:),deg)),2);
out=zeros(size(nn));
out(sub2ind(size(out),R,C)) = vals;
```

---

For a case with input matrix `nn` being *less-sparsey* and really huge, you would feel the bottleneck at computing `bsxfun(@times,nn(R,:).*nn(C,:),deg)`. So, for such a case, you can directly use those `R,C` indices to perform computation for updating respective selective places in the output array.

Thus, an alternative implementation would be -

```
[R,C] = find(triu(nn*nn.',1));
out=zeros(size(nn));
for ii =1:numel(R)
    out(R(ii),C(ii)) = sum(1./log(nn(R(ii),:).*nn(C(ii),:).*deg));
end
```

A middle-ground could probably be estabilshed between the two above mentioned approaches by starting off with the `R,C` indices, then selecting chunks of rows off `nn(R,:)` and respective ones from `nn(C,:)` too and using the vectorized implementation across those chunks iteratively with lesser complexity. Setting the chunk size could be tricky, as it would largely depend on the system resources, input array size involved and the *sparse-ness* of it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this much more compact, much nicer version without fors. I will try to remmeber your tricks (especially bsxfun). I am very surprised, but that version seem to be even slower than the brute-force double-for, for matrices ~500x500. I dont understand and will try to see with the Profiler what happens. Do you have some idea?

Comment: Thank you Divakar, that already gave nearly a factor of two improvement! See my edit. I am still surprised; usually when a double-for is modified into vectorized calculations, it gives a much larger factor of improvement. But that of course depends on the type of algorithm. Anyway - thank you a lot, that helped really much!

Comment: @NicoDean There are alot of things at play when considering a vectorized solution, with memory bandwidth requirements for a large array case being an important one. If you run it on a smaller `nn`, say of size `(100,100)` , the vectorized one would be considerably faster, mainly because of lesser memory requirements. Also, one more point to be noted here specific to your problem - If you weren't doing  `log()`, we would have it reduced to `sum(bsxfun(@times`, which could be then replaced by matrix-multiplication thus speeding it up by a huge margin.